# Autocompletion of syntax when using common files served from CDN (bootstrap, jquery, etc..)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, intellij-idea, webstorm

When writing apps it's common to use files from a CDN (like bootstrap or jquery) without having files locally.  Is there a way to enable autocomplete for common libraries in Webstorm IDE?

If not, any other IDE's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you checked out [this bootstrap plugin](https://github.com/JasonMortonNZ/bootstrap3-phpstorm-plugin) for webstorm? and if you are okay with using a text editor i'd suggest atom. you could get a whole lot of features on it through plugins

Comment: This led me to [live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/live-templates.html?search=live%20templates) which i did not know about.  Thanks!